# Identifying chunks of outliers from a 1D and 2D data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, outliers, chunks

**Data:** I have a data ***d*** in one column which varies as a function of two other variables, ***a*** and ***b***, defined in other two columns. My objective is to identify chunks or outliers in ***d***. Those chunks of outliers might not seem to be outliers, but for my case I want to identify those data that do not fall on a cloud of data that can be fitted with a linear line.

**Problem:**  Even though I have never done cluster analysis before, the name sounded like it could achieve what I am trying to do. In case I chose to do cluster analysis, I would like to do that for two cases as follow:

1. with ***a*** and ***d***
2. with ***a***, ***b*** and ***d***

I did some search and found for #1, using `KernelDensity` module would be more appropriate whereas for #2 using `MeahShift` module would be a good option, both in Python.

**Issue:** I have never done cluster analysis before so I could not understand the examples for both `KernelDensity` and `MeahShift` given in their docs ([here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html), respectively). Could someone please explain how can I use `KernelDensity` and `MeahShift` to identify "chunks" of outliers in ***d*** for case 1 and 2?

Comment: I think you first need a robust regression since your data has been already contaminated by some outliers. Once a robust regression has been fit, then the Mean-Square-Error calculated at each point could serve as a distance measure to cluster centre (the regression line). Those observation with large MSE are possibly outliers.

Comment: reference link for robust regression in sklearn. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#robustness-regression-outliers-and-modeling-errors

Comment: @JianxunLi: I am sorry, but I couldn't understand the example given in that reference..can you show a simple example?

Comment: the code seems to work on your sample data file. I've included in my post, please give a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `KernelDensity` is for non-parametric method. Since you have strong belief that the relation is linear (that is parametric model), `KernelDensity` is not the most appropriate choice in this task.

Below is a sample code to identify the outliers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor


# data: 1000 obs, 100 of them are outliers
# =====================================================
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randn(1000)
b = np.random.randn(1000)
d = 2 * a - b + np.random.randn(1000)
# the last 100 are outliers
d[-100:] = d[-100:] + 10 * np.abs(np.random.randn(100))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0].scatter(a, d, c='g')
axes[0].set_xlabel('a')
axes[0].set_ylabel('d')
axes[1].scatter(b, d, c='g')
axes[1].set_xlabel('b')
```

[image]

```
# processing
# =====================================================
# robust regression
robust_estimator = RANSACRegressor(random_state=0)
robust_estimator.fit(np.vstack([a,b]).T, d)
d_pred = robust_estimator.predict(np.vstack([a,b]).T)

# calculate mse
mse = (d - d_pred.ravel()) ** 2

# get 50 largest mse, 50 is just an arbitrary choice and it doesn't assume that we already know there are 100 outliers
index = argsort(mse)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0].scatter(a[index[:-50]], d[index[:-50]], c='b', label='inliers')
axes[0].scatter(a[index[-50:]], d[index[-50:]], c='r', label='outliers')
axes[0].set_xlabel('a')
axes[0].set_ylabel('d')
axes[0].legend(loc='best')
axes[1].scatter(b[index[:-50]], d[index[:-50]], c='b', label='inliers')
axes[1].scatter(b[index[-50:]], d[index[-50:]], c='r', label='outliers')
axes[1].legend(loc='best')
axes[1].set_xlabel('b')
```

[image]

for your sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor

df = pd.read_excel('/home/Jian/Downloads/Data.xlsx').dropna()

a = df.a.values.reshape(len(df), 1)
d = df.d.values.reshape(len(df), 1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0].scatter(a, d, c='g')
axes[0].set_xlabel('a')
axes[0].set_ylabel('d')

robust_estimator = RANSACRegressor(random_state=0)
robust_estimator.fit(a, d)
d_pred = robust_estimator.predict(a)

# calculate mse
mse = (d - d_pred) ** 2

index = np.argsort(mse.ravel())

axes[1].scatter(a[index[:-50]], d[index[:-50]], c='b', label='inliers', alpha=0.2)
axes[1].scatter(a[index[-50:]], d[index[-50:]], c='r', label='outliers')
axes[1].set_xlabel('a')
axes[1].legend(loc=2)
```

Comment: From what I can understand in your code, you are -1) starting your code with the premise that you already know the outliers,  2) fitting the regression on all the data including the outliers. Also, what is the parameter `T` that you are using in robust regression?

However, my objective is to 1) first decipher those chunks of outliers, 2) fit a linear regression only on the cloud of data lying below the outliers.

Comment: @Pupil No, I don't assume any knowledge on outliers. all the codes on the second half do NOT assume it knows outliers are the last 100 obs. The code above has demonstrate how to remove outliers. You could refit a linear regression using the remaining inliers if you like. the `.T` is just the transpose operator, make sure that each column is a feature.

Comment: Why are you asking the code to mark 50 largest mse as outliers? Basically, I have no idea how many outliers are there or if they are there or not. I want the code to be able to identify those outliers and fit a line on the remaining data without outliers. Also, right now you have included both parameters `a` and `b`; would this work if I include just one parameter, say `a`?

Comment: @Pupil 50 is just an arbitrary choice (5% of the whole dataset). That's similar to use `One Class KMeans` to identify outliers.

Comment: I understand 50 is an arbitrary number. Let's say we want to mark all the outliers as red. What part of code detects those `n` (total number) of outliers? I am sorry, but you are introducing 100 outliers in the beginning, however, I still don't see where does your code identify outliers and how many are they?

Comment: @Pupil no part of the code attempts to find how many outliers are there. By arbitrary, I refer it to a kind of hyperparameter. You might consider using a unsupervised clustering algorithm to cut the data into two clusters, but I don't think that will work. For example, if you feed `mse` into a two cluster `KMeans`, ideally we want the decision boundary to be top-bottom separation. But the result produced by `KMeans` is very likely to have a left-right decision boundary rather than top-bottom.

Comment: Please see the result I get using your method. It doesn't looks like it's giving the result I want..

Comment: @Pupil Can you upload your sample datafile pls? (for example dropbox sharelink) It looks like something goes wrong...

Comment: Jianxun: Thanks for putting up with my doubts. I have few questions in context of this method which I hope you can clarify: 1) Is the `d_pred` based on fitting to blue colored 'inliers' only or it is fitted on all the data i.e. 'inliers+outlier'?, 2) Right now you are plotting 50 outliers, but do we know how many outliers exist in our data through this method?, 3) Let's say I found the slope and intercept of the `d_pred`; is there a quick way of moving this line up or down such that only `5 %` of the total data lie below this linear `d_pred`?

Comment: @Pupil 1) `d_pred` is based on both inliers and outliers, but since we use robust regression, the regression line is robust to outliers. It will produce very very similar regression line if you would like to refit just inliers for another standard linear regression. 2) to my best knowledge, it's very difficult to precisely detect how many outliers in a dataset, you may use the criterion like it's an outlier if its `mse` is 5 times larger than the median of `mse`. 3) you can change the constant and predict new `d_pred` so that `np.percentile(d_pre - d, 0.05)`  gives you `0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for your response to my doubts. In regards to point #3, which constant are you talking about?

Comment: @Pupil the constant of linear regression line. for example, `a0` in `Y = a0 + a1 * X`. Changing value in this constant would shift up/down of the regression line.

Comment: That would just shift the line up or down, however, my question is coupled with the condition that how much should the line be shifted down so that there are only 5% of the raw scatter data below the line.

Comment: @Pupil You need to solve what `a0` makes your function `np.percentile(d_pre - d, 0.05) = 0`. I think it's doable using `scipy` root finding algorithm.